# How do I perform secondary sorting in python?

Tags: python

If i have a list of numbers `[4,2,5,1,3]`
I want to sort it first by some function `f` and then for numbers with the same value of `f` i want it to be sorted by the magnitude of the number.

This code does not seem to be working.

```
list5 = sorted(list5)
list5 = sorted(list5, key = lambda vertex: degree(vertex))
```

Secondary sorting first: list5 is sorted based on magnitude.
Primary sorting next: list5 is sorted based on some function of the numbers.

Comment: btw you can just do `key=degree`, here the `lambda` is redundant

Comment: When you say it "does not seem to be working", what do you observe?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Sort it by a (firstkey, secondkey) tuple:

```
sorted(list5, key=lambda vertex: (degree(vertex), vertex))
```

Comment: To do ascending on one and descending on the other, two calls: list5.sort(key=lambda vertex: vertext, reverse=True) list5.sort(key=lambda vertex: degree(vertext))

Comment: I see why this is a very readable solution, is a very efficient solution also exists? Without coding it yourself, i.e. not computing the second value when unnecessary.

Answer (score 7):

From the Python 3 docs on [sorting](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sortinghowto)

```
from operator import itemgetter, attrgetter
student_objects = [
    Student('john', 'A', 15),
    Student('jane', 'B', 12),
    Student('dave', 'B', 10),
]
student_tuples = [
    ('john', 'A', 15),
    ('jane', 'B', 12),
    ('dave', 'B', 10),
]

#The operator module functions allow multiple levels of sorting. For example, to sort by grade then by age:

sorted(student_tuples, key=itemgetter(1,2))
sorted(student_objects, key=attrgetter('grade', 'age'))
```

Answer (score 5):

On a phone, but youcan sort by tuple.

```
sorted(list5, lambda x: (degree(x),x))
```

Don't forget the reverse flag if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do.

```
s = ['a', 'ac', 'b', 'ab']
s.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]) if len(x)>1 else (x[0],))
```

Result:

```
['a', 'ab', 'ac', 'b']
```